# Why does a Windows 10 PC not restart after BSOD?

Tags: windows-10, bsod

Let me emphasize first that this question is about restart, **not** BSOD diagnosis.

My Windows 10 PC used to restart automatically, but it has not been the case recently.  I have to press the reset button to reboot the PC.

I recently joined Windows Insider Program, but for the most stable ring - Release Preview. I wonder if it has anything to do with it. 
Could anyone offer a tip on how to remedy this?
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[Dump files](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiRcelbJOF1_j-0Ox-9YaB4dfLYYpg?e=H0bNim).

Comment: We cannot fix bugs in Windows, only Microsoft can, so you should report the problem to them. As Windows Insider member you volunteered to beta-test the software and find such problems.

Comment: Windows Insider is only possible culprit.  I hate to go through the long process of reverting back to the previous version to confirm this.  BSO does not happen very often fortunately.  I will report per your suggestion. There are quite some posts about this problem (not on this forum), but no good answers.  It does not seem to be exclusively related to Windows 10 preview.  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/computer-doesnt-restart-after-bsod-error/25a9623f-89e7-4e14-bcd6-e88aea8a3f55

Comment: I have a regular Windows (ver 1909) and the same thing happens: BSOD, the counter goes to 100% and then stays so, even if it says it will restart. This happens on two Lenovo laptops. So it is not related to the Insider program. (I have the "Automatically restart" option ON)